# git merge-base didn't change after a rebase

Tags: git

3 weeks ago, a coworker fixed a problem in prod by commiting to the master without commiting to dev first (and then merging dev on master).

Well Im not sure what happened exactly but there is a problem since that date.

```
> git merge-base dev master
aaabbb
```

when I `git log` for aaabbb, it dates back to Sept 16th. So I wanted to rebase (first time in my life, though I use git merge daily).

I did

```
> git rebase --onto master dev
// fixed a few conflicts
> git pull
> git push
> git merge-base dev master
aaabbb
```

Why is my rebase not working ? I didn't get any warning from git. Thanks!

Comment: What branch were you on when you ran `git rebase --onto master dev`?  The `dev` argument here is the `<upstream>`, so whatever branch you were on then is the one you rebased (while limiting the copies to commits that were on that branch but not on `dev`).

Comment: @torek I was on `dev`. could you rephrase "so whatever branch you were on then is the one you rebased " ? I don't understand that part

Comment: If you were on branch `feature` you would have been rebasing `feature`, and that would immediately explain why `git merge-base dev master` had no changes. If you were on `dev` then it's not clear what has happened here. However, the `git pull` will probably have merged your old `dev` into your new `dev`, which is probably also not good. Meanwhile, adding the output from `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` might help figure out where things stand now.

Comment: thanks but seeing this too late. I finally deleted our dev branch and made a fresh one from master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rebase` ended up in a catastrophe. I have finally end up deleting my `dev` branch and cutting a fresh one from `master`.

And this just happened again. What worked well was to merge `master` into `dev` and merging `dev` into `master` again.